# Simple_HTML_DOM_PARSER not showing data using XPath and Full XPath

Tags: php, web-scraping

I am using simple_html_dom_parser to scrape and show data on my site post from other website's pages.
I was using the following code which was working fine for me.

```
function display_html_info() {
  $html = file_get_html('https://asiftestingsite.online/index.php/2023/11/22/testing-post/');
  $elements = $html->find('div.version div');
  $element = $elements[1];
  return $element->plaintext;
}
add_shortcode('show_this_data', 'display_html_info');
```

The short code shows the data wherever I want in the post.
However, I was struggling to scrape that data that has number of sub divs and span. Therefore I want to use Full XPath to scrape and show data on my post.

```
/html/body/div[3]/main/div[1]/article/div[2]/div/span
```

Due to lack of knowledge about coding, I am unable to do it. Therefore I need your assistance to fix this issue.

I am expecting a solution from the experts.

Comment: *"to scrape and show data on my site post from other website's pages"* Do you have the right to do that?

Comment: @Olivier - Yes!